# Get a value from instantiating class without passing it as argument

Tags: python, inheritance

Is there a way to get a value from `class A` assigned at runtime from `class B` **without** passing it as as argument to the constructor? (e.g. **not** using `new_b = B(self.value)`)

**class_a.py**

```
from class_b import B

class A():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        new_b = B()
```

**class_b.py**

```
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = A.value # here we should get a value from instantiating class A
```

Comment: Not in any manner that would be sane. Pass the argument.

Comment: I mean you could do `new_b = B();` `new_b.value = self.value` but passing the argument is more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but never ever do that. This is bad practice and if you start thinking about doing something like that, you are doing it wrong. Anyway, this line would do it:

```
import inspect

inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1].frame.f_locals["self"].value
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, the more explicit way would be to pass the argument. But, you can try using Super keyword to initialize Base Class methods from where you want to fetch the values.

Refer to this post for your reference,[Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)